# vcpkg cmake integration file doesn't resolve dependency

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to build a program that has dependency on Eigen3 and SDL2.
I'm getting error while using cmake generator command.

Visual Studio 17 2022 is the default generator on my PC. I've checked this with `cmake --help` command.

`C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake` is the location of my vcpkg cmake intergeration file is located.

I've installed bith Eigen3 and SDL2 dependency via vcpkg.

Build Command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake

cmake .. "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"

cmake ..
```

I even tried

```
cmake .. "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\eigen3"
```

Error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

CMake File

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5) project(AKFSFSimulation)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

set(SRC_CPP
    src/main.cpp
    src/display.cpp
    src/beacons.cpp
    src/sensors.cpp
    src/simulation.cpp
    src/utils.cpp
    src/kalmanfilter.cpp )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${SRC_CPP}
        )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        SDL2
        SDL2_ttf
        Eigen3::Eigen
        )

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/data/ $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

Eigen Installation

```
λ .\vcpkg.exe install eigen3 Computing installation plan... The following packages are already installed:
    eigen3:x64-windows -> 3.4.0#2 eigen3:x64-windows is already installed Total install time: 491 us eigen3 provides CMake targets:

    # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
    find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

---

Eigen3 Installation Output

```
λ .\vcpkg.exe install eigen3
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    eigen3:x64-windows -> 3.4.0#2
eigen3:x64-windows is already installed
Total install time: 344 us
eigen3 provides CMake targets:

    # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
    find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

Comment: retry with manifest mode. If it install Eigen3 and can still not find it try dropping the version requirement.

Comment: out of curiosity, what if you do `find_package (Eigen3 3.4 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)`? [related docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-version-selection). Does the Eigen package come with a eigen3-version.cmake or Eigen3Version.cmake file?

Comment: @starball I tried with version 3.4 and also no specifying specific version. I still get the same error. I couldn't find `eigen3-version.cmake` or `Eigen3Version.cmake` file in vcpkg folder.

Comment: huh. then try `find_package (Eigen3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)` From those docs I linked: "_When the [version] argument is given, Config mode will only find a version of the package that claims compatibility with the requested version (see format specification) \[...\] If no such version file is available then the configuration file is assumed to not be compatible with any requested version._"

Comment: @starball I already tried that but no joy. I'm getting the error `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any  of the following names: 
    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake`

Comment: 1) what does vcpkg print when you install Eigen3? It should print instructions for depending on it. 2) Do either of those two config files exist in the installation directory?

Comment: @starball 1. I've added the reponse of `.\vcpkg.exe install eigen3` command. 2. Neither of the 2 config files are available in the installation directory.

Comment: ok... and what do you get when you follow the heuristically generated instructions? Also, what's `NO_MODULE` and why are you adding it?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/4185

Comment: The `find_package` call should work. Run your configure command with --trace-expand and make sure to run configure in a clean directory without an already populated CMakCache.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eigen3Config.cmake` is located in the folder `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\share\eigen3`.
Setting `Eigen3_DIR` to `<vcpkg-root>/installed/x64-windows/share/eigen3` solved the issue.
e.g. Set `Eigen3_DIR` to `c:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/eigen3` in my case.